# Global variables, Parallel computation and Limiting notebook's context

Tags: parallelization, scoping

If I limit the context of each notebook:

[image]

and use parallel computation:

```
ParallelTable[ToExpression["b" <> ToString[j]], {j, 1, 10}]
```

then after computation instead getting this:

```
{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10}
```

I get this:

```
{Global`b1, Global`b2, Global`b3, Global`b4, Global`b5, Global`b6, Global`b7, Global`b8, Global`b9, Global`b10}
```

How can I get the rid of `Global`?

`DistributeDefinitions` didn't help.
I use MMA 9.

Comment: I get your first expression (no `Global`` context).  I should mention, though, that the default context that I use is `Unique to This Notebook`.  Perhaps, you set your notebook context too late into the session.

Comment: My comment above3 is based on MMA10.  Using MMA9, I obtain your second result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented earlier, with a notebook configured as in your question, I obtain your first answer with MMA V10 and your second answer with MMA V9.  Evidently, Wolfram Inc identified the V9 behavior as a problem and fixed it in V10.  Since the problem occurs for `ToExpression` run in `ParallelTable`, perhaps

```
ToExpression[ParallelTable["b" <> ToString[j], {j, 1, 10}]]
```

would address your need, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

When I change my settings: Menu bar >> Evaluation >> Notebook's default context >> Global', I get the desired output

```
{b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10}
```